# how to wrangle float.sty, caption.sty, and wrapfig.sty interaction

Tags: floats, captions, wrapfigure

I am writing a book that has figures, which are ruled and with fancy captions.  Now I decided I also want to insert a few cartoons into my paragraphs.  I need the text to wrap around them, which is why I need wrapfig. (I don't need the float aspect of wrapfig, because I prefer to place the figures.)

Unfortunately, I get an unpleasant interaction.  Being a float figure, the horizontal rules from ruled figures are showing even when I do not want them in my cartoons (and weirdly, too; the top rule is behind, the bottom rule is in front of the text):

[image]

Is there a version that just wraps text around, without relying on figure (float)?

The creating source is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat*{figure}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\definecolor{lightyellow}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,0.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.35\textwidth}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  {\color{lightyellow}\fbox{\rule{0.28\textwidth}{13em}}}
  \vspace{-25pt}%
\end{wrapfigure}%

Consider our planet's historical human population.  Even as recently as 5,000~BC---almost 200,000~years after the rise of homo sapiens---the human population was still tiny, approximately 5 million people.  Around the time of the Han, Mayan, Parthian, and Roman empires, the planet hosted about 150--200~million people.  By the end of the middle ages, it stood around 400~million.   Humanity's impact on the global environment was still largely negligible---though we probably did manage to wipe out some species, not only the Woolly Mammoth but also other human species.

\begin{figure}

shows the rules, because box has content

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

%% shows nothing.  nice

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The `wrapfigure` environment is just defined via

```
\def\wrapfigure{\wrapfloat{figure}}
```

so you can define a similar environment that isn't `wrapfigure` or just use `wrapfloat` directly. The `caption` package won't modify float types that have not been specifically styled.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat*{figure}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\definecolor{lightyellow}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,0.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfloat}{notfigure}{l}{0.35\textwidth}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  {\color{lightyellow}\fbox{\rule{0.28\textwidth}{13em}}}
  \vspace{-25pt}%
\end{wrapfloat}%

Consider our planet's historical human population.  Even as recently as 5,000~BC---almost 200,000~years after the rise of homo sapiens---the human population was still tiny, approximately 5 million people.  Around the time of the Han, Mayan, Parthian, and Roman empires, the planet hosted about 150--200~million people.  By the end of the middle ages, it stood around 400~million.   Humanity's impact on the global environment was still largely negligible---though we probably did manage to wipe out some species, not only the Woolly Mammoth but also other human species.

\begin{figure}

shows the rules, because box has content

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

%% shows nothing.  nice

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but then you can't use \caption inside the wrap-nofigure but will have to use \captionof. Also caption does redefine \wrapfloat, but it is not ruled as float doesn't know the non-figure.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes sure, although I read the question as not needing captions, but as you say captionof is available

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but I'll re-word the "does not know" as it's misleading I agree

Comment: But I wonder why caption patches wrapfloat for this. wrapfig contains support for float.sty and with its code you have some control through the package loading order if a style affect the wrapfig. caption seems to do everything at begin document.

Comment: thanks.  marked as solved.  also, is it possible to get rid of the floating aspect altogether and just have the cutout?

Comment: @ivoWelch wrapfigure doesn't really float it just re-uses some of the float mechanism as (normally) you want to pick up similar styling, but by avoiding the figure styling there isn't much left.  You could of course just use a parshape directly and not use wrapfigure at all but wrapfig handles special cases like the first paragraph being short so some of the cut-in carrying over to a later paragraph

Comment: I did not know about parshape.  yes, I do need the ability to go over multiple paragraphs.  thanks again.

Comment: @ivoWelch carrying over the parshape on to subsequent paragraphs is by far the trickiest bit of wrapfig, if you want that I'd use wrapfig as here and then stop it doing whatever you don't want it to do, it is likely much easier than not using wrapfig then writing that code from scatch.